# XQuery for remote XML

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery, basex

Populating the `baseX` database with [locally](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-examples/src/main/java/org/basex/examples/local/CreateCollection.java) stored data is straight forward.  But how would remote `XML` be [fetched](http://www.codecoffee.com/articles/xml1.html)?

---

> XQuery
>
> The HTML Module provides a function for converting HTML to XML
>   documents.
>
> Documents can also be converted by specifying the parser and
>   additional options in the query prolog:

```
declare option db:parser "html";
declare option db:htmlparser "html=false,nodefaults=true";
doc("index.html")
```

https://basex.readthedocs.io/en/search/Parsers/#xquery

To make concrete:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ cat html_fetch_parse.xq 


fetch:xml("http://books.toscrape.com/", map {
  'parser': 'html',
  'htmlparser': map { 'html': false(), 'nodefaults': true() }
})

thufir@dur:~/basex$
```

But what if the document is already `XML`?

`HTML` is [fetched](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53995437/262852) reasonably easily.  Surely `XML` is even simpler.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the `fetch:xml` does simply returns fetched nodes and it doesn't insert the nodes in any data base. As for simply loading XML, you can also use the `doc` function, e.g. use `doc('http://example.com/foo.xml')`. To work with data bases from XQuery, see the module http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module, for instance http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module#db:add or http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module#db:create e.g. `db:create("DB", doc('http://example.com/foo.xml'), 'foo.xml')`.

Answer (score 0):

This [code](https://github.com/THUFIR/helloWorldBaseX) populates a database in `baseX` correctly:

```
package org.basex.examples.local;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.basex.core.BaseXException;
import org.basex.core.Context;
import org.basex.core.Databases;
import org.basex.core.cmd.CreateDB;
import org.basex.core.cmd.DropDB;
import org.basex.core.cmd.List;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Set;
import org.basex.util.list.StringList;

public class ScraperForXML {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    private Properties properties = new Properties();

    private ScraperForXML() {
    }

    public ScraperForXML(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
        LOG.fine(properties.toString());
    }

    public void fetch() throws BaseXException, MalformedURLException   {
        URL url = new URL(properties.getProperty("xmlURL"));
        String databaseName = properties.getProperty("databaseName");

        Context context = new Context();
        LOG.info(new List().execute(context));

        new Set("parser", "xml").execute(context);
        new CreateDB(databaseName, url.toString()).execute(context);


        Databases databases = context.databases();
        StringList stringListOfDatabases = databases.listDBs();
        String currentDatabaseName = null;

        Iterator<String> databaseIterator = stringListOfDatabases.iterator();

        while (databaseIterator.hasNext()) {
            currentDatabaseName=databaseIterator.next();
            LOG.info(currentDatabaseName);
            //not quite sure how to query a database...
        }


        new DropDB(databaseName).execute(context);
        context.close();
    }

}
```

although it's not an actual `XQuery` which is the goal.